# Production Site fails to notify

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3

When my notify code runs when it is supposed to, I am getting the error Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" on my Laravel 5.3 production site. When I look at the full stack trace, it seems to be caching old-incorrect login credentials. I have checked and double checked the updated 'config/mail.php' file and the .env file. The stack trace is showing "Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_LoginAuthenticator->authenticate(object(Swift_SmtpTransport" with totally outdated credentials that are different from the afore mentioned updated files. I have run "sudo systemctl restart nginx" and "php artisan cache:clear" with no change. Can someone tell me how to address this error message more effectively? Is there a different file I need to update? or setting? Everything works fine on my dev machine using mailtrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Laravel 5.3 > Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#configuration-caching)
You should typically run the `php artisan config:cache` command as part of your production deployment routine.

Run `php artisan config:cache` and restart your server. This will scrap loaded/cached configuration files data.

Comment: Glad to help you...! Merry xmas...:)